Why do motor controller inverter sections use decoupling capacitors of a single value?
I've been looking at several reference designs for motor controllers, and I've noticed that the decoupling capacitors on the metal-clad inverter boards are always of a single value. Wouldn't it be more effective to use multiple values of decoupling capacitors? This approach could provide a broader range of filtering and help avoid any resonance peak overlaps.
Would it be better to have multiple values of decoupling caps? the current design has 10 decoupling caps of 10uF value, would it be better to reduce the number of 10uF caps and replace it with some 1uF or 0.1uF caps?
I'm referring to the ceramic caps that are used and not DC link caps

It depends. We can't really know the properties of the caps and what is required of them. Are you talking about ceramics, electrolytics or something else?

Guessing inventory&manufacturing cost, even discounts.

A lot depends on the layout and what the board does.  For FPGA based designs, what you have suggested is a good starting point.  Absent any analysis or simulation of the PDN (Power Distribution Network), decoupling is usually based on 1) manufacturer's recommendations and 2) past experience.

Fewer BOM lines? Biggest capacity available in a particular capsule size? Volume discounts?

An inverter bypass application demands low impedance at up to modest frequencies, typically mid 10s of MHz.  But it can extend up into the 100s MHz, particularly for modern transistors driven hard, or SiC, and GaN especially.  Transistor choice and drive strength/speed are design parameters like any others.
Resonance peaks are prominent if ESR < \$\sqrt{\frac{ESL}{C}}\$.  Most likely, the layout can be arranged, and parts chosen, such that resonance is avoided.
Note that staggered values, and chip sizes, are largely a mythical approach anyway: back in the days of ceramic disks, it was perhaps a viable strategy, but MLCCs are largely equivalent by chip size so there is no advantage to using say a 0603 in 10nF or 100nF, over 1 or 10µF, such as for digital / ASIC / SoC supply bypass.
Whatever the case, the small-signal (RLC) parameters of the capacitor can be modeled with an equivalent circuit, extracting stray inductance of the PCB layout by making assumptions on trace length and geometry.  (Extraction can be done automatically by a field solver, such as several ANSYS products for example.)  One can then apply realistic signals to the network, and observe its response: applying a 10s-of-amperes current step from the inverter, for example.  A typical parallel-planes layout can have single-digit nH of stray inductance between components on the plane(s), and MLCCs of this value have single-digit ESR; we find resonance is suppressed for \$C > \frac{ESL}{ESR^2}\$ or 10µF, which checks out.
Note that type 2 MLCCs (X7R, etc.) are NOT rated value under DC voltage bias.  The C(V) curve drops significantly towards rated voltage.  This can encourage some resonance once again; but a modest peak can still be acceptable.

There's several reasons to use only one primary value.

0.1uF is 'good enough' for most applications

0.1uF hits a sweet spot for bypassing, doing a decent job in the 1-100Mhz region. More here: Where did the value of 0.1uF for bypass capacitors come from?
Also note that in smaller packages, the parasitics that bedevil capacitors in larger packages are much reduced, especially inductance (ESL). This makes the humble 0.1uF even more effective at higher frequency. More here: Self resonance frequency for MLCC capacitor

Fewer BOM items

Having a large number of different capacitor types adds to the BOM line item count. Further, if the mix values are bought in lower quantities then you have higher costs associated with them.

Anti-resonance

Mixing values must be done with care to avoid anti-resonance, a phenomenon where the caps overall responses interact with each other and make higher-impedance 'peaks' that actually make the overall bypass performance worse than just using a single value. More here: How to calculate values for decoupling capacitors
What if I want to do value mixing?
tl; dr: to do value mixing correctly, you simulate your power network using real models of your caps that include parasitics.
A rule of thumb to avoid anti-resonance is to space your values by 5-10x. That's why you'll often see 0.1uf used together with 0.01uF and 1000pF on the near-pin end; and 1uF / 10uF / 47uF on power supply (bulk) end. This is kind of a lazy, yet safe way to go about it.
A cheap-and-cheetrful way is to use the Kemet (now Yageo) K-sim tool to model multiple caps to get a sanity check. You could also use various Spice tools (like LTSpice) using vendor models.
Really though, very careful value mixing using more-closely spaced value mixing to achieve the lowest possible / broadest range low impedance power distribution is a more exotic technique that's costly in both time and software. It's usually reserved for designs that use really high switching rates and need a very low EMI profile.
For a high-volume cutting-edge product like a smartphone it's probably be worth it. Most of the time it isn't. Nevertheless if you're lucky enough to have access to a reference design where the vendor has done this value-mixing legwork for you, by all means follow it (and also follow their layout too.)
